# Can't add more than one space in the string

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $str1 = 'merry';
    $str2 = 'christmas';
    $concat = $str1.'      '.$str2;
    echo $concat;
?>
```

I concated or concatenated whatever more than one sapce but the result is only one space, can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `&nbsp;`

```
    <?php

    $str1 = 'merry';
    $str2 = 'christmas';
    $concat = $str1.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$str2;
    echo $concat;
?>
```

Comment: Awesome mate, it worked. Thanks a lot.